# NativeActivity and GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, android-ndk, google-play

I am trying to get a NativeActivity app to implement GooglePlayServices. I'm currently trying to do this by creating my own class that extends NativeActivity.

My Google Play services Revision is 18 shown in my Android SDK Manager. I am running on a device that is running Android API 10.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
```

Here is a snippet from my activity

```
public class KablamActivity extends NativeActivity {

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this.getApplicationContext());
}

}
```

The following output is saying my Google Play services is out of date as well, but there is supposed to be a dialog popping up telling me something. What do I need to do to resolve the android.app.AlertDialog and android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager issues?

```
dalvikvm Could not find method android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.a
dalvikvm VFY: unable to resolve direct method 79: Landroid/app/AlertDialog$Builder;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;I)V
dalvikvm VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x002c
dalvikvm Could not find method android.app.Activity.getFragmentManager, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b
dalvikvm VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 28: Landroid/app/Activity;.getFragmentManager ()Landroid/app/FragmentManager;
dalvikvm VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0023
dalvikvm VFY: dead code 0x0026-0030 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (ILandroid/app/Activity;Landroid/support/v4/app/Fragment;ILandroid/content/DialogInterface$OnCancelListener;)Z
dalvikvm DexOpt: couldn't find field Landroid/content/res/Configuration;.smallestScreenWidthDp
dalvikvm VFY: unable to resolve instance field 53
dalvikvm VFY: replacing opcode 0x52 at 0x0012
dalvikvm VFY: dead code 0x0014-0018 in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil;.b (Landroid/content/res/Resources;)Z
GooglePlayServicesUtil Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5077000 but found 4452034
```

Comment: I have same issue, did you get any solution ?

Comment: There was nothing to be done about it. The old version just worked though having those errors.